# Extending Identity3 in MVC6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

using the latest (current) RC1 of asp.net5 I'm looking at creating a simple relationship between a **User** entity and a **WorkLog** entity.

Is it possible to use the ApplicationUser Class from Identity as a starting point and use the ApplicationUser key which is defined as the linking key? I have had problems extending the ApplicationUser in the past and therefore generated a seperate dbcontext (pointing to the same database) and created my own plumbing in order to pass the IdentityUsers Id into my seperate dbcontext. Does anyone have any examples of extending the IdentityDbContext adding foreign key tables mapping to the IdentityUser Class?

Example below

```
//DBContext
     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public DbSet<WorkLogItem> WorkLogItems { get; set; }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);
                // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
                // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
                // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
                builder.Entity<WorkLogItem>(
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.Property(p => p.id).IsRequired().UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
                    });
            }
        }
//WorkLogItem
    public class WorkLogItem
    {
        public int id { get; set;}
        public String UserId { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }
//ApplicationUser
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<WorkLogItem> WorkLogItems { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing what you've asked is expected to work out of the box.  You can look at [this commit](https://github.com/staff0rd/extending-identity/commit/42625cf5658cc28ae5424fa23399be92fe96edba) to see the difference between a newly created MVC 6 project with Identity and your schema above.

Registering a user, and refreshing /Home/Index causes `WorkLogItem`s to be added as expected.  Note you don't need a separate DB context for this.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var user = _db.Users.Include(p => p.WorkLogItems).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.WorkLogItems.Add(new WorkLogItem { Description = "New item added" });
        _db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.WorkItems = user.WorkLogItems.ToList();
    }
    else ViewBag.WorkItems = new WorkLogItem[] { };

    return View();
}
```

The key items to be aware of when you add any collection to an existing entity are;

1. Make sure you add the migration and update the databse
2. Make sure you use `Include` on the query because [EF7 does not support Lazy Loading](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3797).

Comment: great help, really helpful when i browsed that repo.